# array_searching not working for certain array

Tags: php, arrays

This is the array ($results):

```
Array ( [0] => b [1] => h [2] => l [3] => p [4] => s [5] => u )
```

This is the code:

```
echo array_search("h",$results);
```

For some reason it's returning nothing and I cannot figure why it's returning nothing.

On the other hand, if I have an identical array ($houses):

```
Array ( [0] => b [1] => h [2] => l [3] => p [4] => s [5] => u )
```

It correctly returns the position of "h", 1, when the following code is used:

```
echo array_search("h",$houses);
```

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 hours now but I just don't understand. Help would be appreciated... thanks.

Comment: Is `$results` override somewhere?

Comment: `var_dump($results)`, be sure you know *exactly* what your array contains. Any extraneous whitespace maybe...? Also `var_dump(array_search(..))`; a function never returns "nothing", it always returns *something*.

Comment: This is what var_dump($results) is returning: `array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "b" [1]=> string(2) " h" [2]=> string(2) " l" [3]=> string(2) " p" [4]=> string(2) " s" [5]=> string(2) " u" }`

Comment: A string of length `2`...? That is not just an "h".

Comment: Oh... yes, I've just noticed, it contains a space. That makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array( "b","h","l","p","s","u" ); //This array is indexed like yours
echo array_search("h", $results); //Output is 1
```

Remember the rules for making arrays:
*seperate values with commas
*quote index markers (ie: array("indexA"=>"value");)

*give indexes vaules using =>

Using these parameters your arrays should be fine.